# Hide folder in asp.net with deny roles

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, authorization

I have this configuration below to hide a folder from users in a specific group. It works on one domain but when I trying to deploy it to another one it doesn't. 
I know that the settings is in the right place in the web.config and right formatted because if I change to deny users="*" no one will see it the folder (almost like I want but I want only hide for a specific AD group) and I know for a fact that I have the right AD group for it too since I'm using it in my code (doing a IsInRole check).

```
<location path="Folder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny roles="domain\group"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

- Using Windows Athentications

What can I have missed on the second IIS/Domain? (Don't forget that it works on the "first" Domain/IIS)

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work".  Everyone can access or no one can access, or what explicitly isn't working?  Could there be an issue with the second IIS server having access to that domain?  Are you enabling directory browsing, becaues usually users don't know about a "folder" per se.

Comment: doesn't work = everyone can see 'Folder'. Its accually not real folder but MVC paths, but it works as I wish on the first domain/iis. Any ideas about IIS settings that can interfere?

Comment: Yeah, both are on the same authentication mode (forms or windows), right?  Also, both servers are the same version of IIS and OS?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make the first iis that worked to have the same settings as the one that didn't but obviously I failed. When I found the problem it was that Anonymous - was enabled and Windows Authentications was disabled, I switch those and It now works. (I'm sure I trided to set the "working" iis in the same Authentication state but since that was of an older version I may have failed)